# JSONParser getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working in a project and I need a resource in it. I am trying to get it using this code:

> InputStream is =
> JSONParser.class.getResourceAsStream("a.json");
> String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );

The file a.json is located in the main file of the project.

The exact problem is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)  
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)  
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1049)  
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:359)  
    at com.playence.parser.JSon.main(JSon.java:28)
```

Debugging, I saw that variable 'is' is null, and I guess that is why NullPointException, bugt I don't know how to solve it.

Any help?

Thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my problem and I solved it.
It was related with my Eclipse configuration:

Project - propperties - Source

There I had in Myproject/src/main/resources Exclude **.

So the files in that directory wasn't in classes. I solved it just putting Exclude (None).

Now everything is ok.
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You have the exception because `a.json` can't be found by your [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) in which case this returns null instead of the stream.

Your `a.json` file should be in the same package as the `JSONParser` class the way you have it now. Is that one of your classes or is a utils from an external library?

If it is a library, maybe you can retrieve the stream from a class that is in the same package as `a.json` and then pass it as parameter:

```
InputStream is = YourClassBesidesTheFile.class.getResourceAsStream("a.json");
String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );
```

or maybe use a full path for the file, something like `"/some/package/etc/etc/a.json"`:

```
InputStream is = JSONParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/some/package/etc/etc/a.json");
String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString( is );
```

To solve the issue, your file must be found by the `Class.getResourceAsStream()` method although the real issue is in fact retrieving the file content as a stream, no matter how you do that.

Comment: I put the file in src/main/resorces, and also Y tryed putting it into the same file that the class which is is calling it, but I get the same error.
Typing the hole path is also the same result.
Maybe could it be a problem with ecplipse and libraries??

Comment: By the way, I am using JSONParser by importing maven dependencies, I have not JSONParser.java in my project.

Comment: @mujer-esponja: I see you are using src/main/resorces folder. Are you using Maven?

Comment: @mujer-esponja: the files you place in src/main/resorces are placed exactly as is in your jar (I assume you are building a jar or using a maven project, see here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR). You can add the file with a sub-package path the same as the class that reads it and then retrieve it as such (like in my example) or I guess that JSONParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/a.json") should work. It depends on your environment.